# Classifying Days in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking for a method to classify days of the week as either weekend or weekday. I currently have a column in my excel table that looks like this:

```
    Days
    Monday 
    Tuesday 
    Sunday
    Friday
```

My goal is to create a column next to the above table as follows:

```
    Days    Type
   Monday  Weekday 
   Tuesday Weekday 
   Sunday  Weekend
   Friday  Weekday
```

Is there any way to be able to do this process maybe with a formula or something? I cannot do it manually because there are hundreds of rows. I can't use add-ons either because they are blocked by my job and its a long process just to download an add-on.

Comment: Seems like you can just check if the first letter is S

Answer (score 2):

If Days are in A1 downwards, put this formula in B1 and copy downwards

`=IF(MATCH(A1, {"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"}, 0) < 6, "Weekday", "Weekend")`

Answer (score 2):

=IF(OR(A1="Monday";A1="Tuesday";A1="Wednesday";A1="Thursday";A1="Friday");"Weekday";"Weekend")

Answer (score 2):

With data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=LOOKUP(A1,{"Friday","Monday","Saturday","Sunday'","Thursday","Tuesday","Wednesday"},{"weekday","weekday","weekend","weekend","weekday","weekday","weekday"})
```

[image]

*NOTE:*

*The days in the formula as in alphabetic order.*

Answer (score 2):

Three more,

```
=choose(iferror(sign(match(a1, {"Saturday","Sunday"}, 0))+1, 1), "Weekday", "Weekend") 

=choose(isnumber(match(a1, {"Saturday","Sunday"}, 0))+1, "Weekday", "Weekend")

=choose(or(a1={"Saturday","Sunday"})+1, "Weekday", "Weekend")
```

Comment: Like these, only check for the two important days and all the others are ok... very minimalist :)

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer Jeeped's methods.  But here are another two:

`=IF(OR(A2={"Saturday","Sunday"}),"Weekend","Weekday")`

If you really hate typing:

`="Week"&IF(OR(A2={"Saturday","Sunday"}),"end","day")`